# Codeigniter librarys vs core classes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need to create some functionality that will be used by nearly all my controllers.

So I need to create a custom class. Now do I do this as a Core class? Or as a library? How do these differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the core class override technique when there's some behavior of one of the core classes that I want to change project wide. A great example of this is using [Jamie Rumbelow's model class](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model) in /core/MY_Model.

For functionality that will be USED in each controller, I build a library to perform those functions and autoload it, then call the functions from that library as needed.

Comment: +1!  Exactly! Classes placed in the core folder should be classes that override the CodeIgniter classes. If you're writing your own classes with their own functionality - then that's a library.

Comment: he functionality WILL require database interaction. But it will also store/retrieve data in sessions. As such, does it make sense to have both a library and a model? Or just a model?

Comment: Yes, you'll have a model too...the model will handle database interactions. Your library will call methods in the model to retrieve or store data in the database. It's not so much an either/or as it is a comprehensive system made up of individual components that each do their own job.

Answer (score 0):

You want a library is you are developing a class.  For simple functions, create a helper.  If you are developing functionality that interacts with your database, create a model.

Add your custom helpers and libraries in you application folder.

Comment: The functionality WILL require database interaction. But it will also  store/retrieve data in sessions.

As such, does it make sense to have both a library and a model?

Comment: Yes, your library will call methods in the model for data retrieval.

Comment: Thank you. Jcorry. On a side note: how do you like Jamie Rumbelow's model class? Does it make your developing faster?

I was also thinking about getting her book (https://efendibooks.com/books/codeigniter-handbook/vol-1). Any opinion?

Comment: Jamie is a she? I had no idea! I really like that class...but see that it has limitations. Some purists argue that building models that represent DB tables is a design anti-pattern. I have noticed (over 12 years of PHP development) that this 'anti-pattern' is really useful for the types of problems I am repeatedly asked to solve. I'm not familiar with the book...but have never read a codeigniter book, it's user guide and the tutorials available online and opensource apps written with it are all SO useful for developing as a CI user that I haven't seen the need.